# How to set .env values in laravel programmatically on the fly

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

I have a custom CMS that I am writing from scratch in Laravel and want to set `env` values i.e. database details, mailer details, general configuration, etc from controller once the user sets up and want to give user the flexibility to change them on the go using the GUI that I am making.

So my question is how do I write the values received from user to the `.env` file as an when I need from the controller.

And is it a good idea to build the `.env` file on the go or is there any other way around it?

Comment: According to my opinion the env variables shouldn't be modified as env variables are not made for modifications, instead they should guide the app wih robust values. You should try another trick/hack to achieve your goal.

Comment: I agree with @SaumyaRastogi...env variables should not be modified

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi I needed this to make repo installing easier by copying a randomly generated app token that I need to store in `.env`. So there are legit uses.

Comment: @totymedli I don’t think so that it’s a legit use, instead make use of laravel commands like `php artisan some_command`. Laravel also uses `php artisan key:generate` to generate random key for the app. Maybe this helps you!

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi I use that. I set the `.env` file from there. The key is generated to the db. Without copying it to the `.env` file, I would have to fetch it in every request.

Comment: In my case vendor lib for Telegram bot uses env var for bot token. When I override env var - I upgrades this lib from single-bot mode to multi-bot mode. But yeah - there is another way without modifying of env var, but not so "short".

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Since Laravel uses config files to access and store `.env` data, you can set this data on the fly with `config()` method:

```
config(['database.connections.mysql.host' => '127.0.0.1']);
```

To get this data use `config()`:

```
config('database.connections.mysql.host')
```

> To set configuration values at runtime, pass an array to the `config` helper

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

Comment: `config(['something'=> 'data']);
return env('something');`
This is how I set it in controller but it is not returning anything.

Comment: You don't need to use `env()`. Just set data with `config()` and then get data with `config('something')`.

Comment: I setup my database credentials on runtime using this method and also have removed it from the .env file but it takes the default values ie. forge@localhost so this method is not working, I dont just want to put configuration, I even want to setup env variables like database details, mailing details, etc

Comment: It means you're using wrong path when trying to set data. Please give me example of what are you doing and then I'll be able to help you with it.

Comment: `config(['DB_HOST'=> '127.0.0.1']);
config(['DB_PORT'=> '3306']);
config(['DB_DATABASE'=> 'qbi_cms']);
config(['DB_USERNAME'=> 'root']);
config(['DB_PASSWORD'=> '']);
Auth::routes();
` This is from my routes file

Comment: It is like when you setup wordpress, it walks you through the process of setting up various things, so thats what even I want to do, I dont want the user to need to go the .env file to setup these things, they should be able to do this with GUI

Comment: You're doing it wrong. I've updated my answer with code which will work for changing DB host. You're trying to use `.env` variables when Laravel uses config ones. Look into `config\database.php` and you'll understand how it works.

Comment: This one worked very nicely, BTW where did you get this, coz I went through the docs and there did not seem anything in this direction. Also I will need to see how other settings are to be setup so please pass a link if you have one for reference. Thanks

Comment: Mostly from docs. There is a link in my answer, read whole page and look into `config\database.php` if you want to understand how it works. )

Comment: where to put this code? I mean where to set the config values dynamically. I have a handful of settings I get from the database which I need to set at the run time as config. So where else should I do it? The controller is not an option because I need those values in the Jobs, queues and commands as well. I need to set it globally for the current instance of the application.

Comment: @Vignesh you can do that almost from any part of an app. Use `config(['variable' => $value])`

Comment: Thanks for your timely help mate. I just noticed that the junior was used env('key') directly inside the controller and some other places. Setting it to config won't override it now right? Do I need to change those places manually?

Comment: Normally you use `env()` in config files. In this case, you'll be able to override default settings.

Comment: For the noobs. If you haven't worked with `config` yet (like me), you will have to create a new configuration like for example in `config/services` you create a new entry `myservice => [ 'price' => env('ENV_VARIABLE_PRICE') ]`. Then you can use it like described above.

Answer (score 49):

Watch out! Not all variables in the laravel .env are stored in the config environment.
To overwrite real .env content use simply:

**putenv ("CUSTOM_VARIABLE=hero");**

To read as usual, env('CUSTOM_VARIABLE') or env('CUSTOM_VARIABLE', 'devault')

NOTE: Depending on which part of your app uses the env setting, you may need to set the variable early by placing it into your index.php or bootstrap.php file. Setting it in your app service provider may be too late for some packages/uses of the env settings.

Comment: If you /really/ have to change env values at runtime, this seems a much better way to go than hacking the file's contents.

Comment: This is really good for unit testing with agency work where you will use the template again and want to set up weird environments that arent solved with phpunit.xml since its static

Comment: please mention that this does not edit the actual .env file in laravel and could be replaced  by the next request with values in the actual .env file

Comment: This is the best answer. I am using it to change the APP_URL because i have domian aliases and the APP_URL need to be set as $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Answer (score 22):

More simplified:

```
public function putPermanentEnv($key, $value)
{
    $path = app()->environmentFilePath();

    $escaped = preg_quote('='.env($key), '/');

    file_put_contents($path, preg_replace(
        "/^{$key}{$escaped}/m",
        "{$key}={$value}",
        file_get_contents($path)
    ));
}
```

or as helper:

```
if ( ! function_exists('put_permanent_env'))
{
    function put_permanent_env($key, $value)
    {
        $path = app()->environmentFilePath();

        $escaped = preg_quote('='.env($key), '/');

        file_put_contents($path, preg_replace(
            "/^{$key}{$escaped}/m",
           "{$key}={$value}",
           file_get_contents($path)
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: `file_put_contents($path, preg_replace("/^{$key}.*$/m", "{$key}={$value}", file_get_contents($path)));`

Answer (score 17):

Based on totymedli's answer.

Where it is required to change multiple enviroment variable values at once, you could pass an array (key->value). Any key not present previously will be added and a bool is returned so you can test for success.

```
public function setEnvironmentValue(array $values)
{

    $envFile = app()->environmentFilePath();
    $str = file_get_contents($envFile);

    if (count($values) > 0) {
        foreach ($values as $envKey => $envValue) {

            $str .= "\n"; // In case the searched variable is in the last line without \n
            $keyPosition = strpos($str, "{$envKey}=");
            $endOfLinePosition = strpos($str, "\n", $keyPosition);
            $oldLine = substr($str, $keyPosition, $endOfLinePosition - $keyPosition);

            // If key does not exist, add it
            if (!$keyPosition || !$endOfLinePosition || !$oldLine) {
                $str .= "{$envKey}={$envValue}\n";
            } else {
                $str = str_replace($oldLine, "{$envKey}={$envValue}", $str);
            }

        }
    }

    $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
    if (!file_put_contents($envFile, $str)) return false;
    return true;

}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'm trying to use this but the .env file never updates to what I pass as values. No errors or anything either, really weird. Tried a few other solutions in this threads but none works. Got any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 15):

Based on josh's answer. I needed a way to replace the value of a key inside the `.env` file.

But unlike josh's answer, I did not want to depend on knowing the current value or the current value being accessible in a config file at all.

Since my goal is to replace values that are used by Laravel Envoy which doesn't use a config file at all but instead uses the `.env` file directly.

Here's my take on it:

```
public function setEnvironmentValue($envKey, $envValue)
{
    $envFile = app()->environmentFilePath();
    $str = file_get_contents($envFile);

    $oldValue = strtok($str, "{$envKey}=");

    $str = str_replace("{$envKey}={$oldValue}", "{$envKey}={$envValue}\n", $str);

    $fp = fopen($envFile, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $str);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Usage:

```
$this->setEnvironmentValue('DEPLOY_SERVER', 'forge@122.11.244.10');
```

Comment: The `strtok()` part does not work for me. I replaced it to: `$oldValue = env($envKey);`

Comment: @PiotrSuchanek That won't work with variables using double quotes like: `KEY="Something with spaces or variables ${KEY2}"`. See a [better solution in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52548022/1494454).

Comment: The `strtok()` method splits given `string`, with second argument as delimiter, and returns anything before delimiter. Also is a lot faster than other split methods. I mean, maybe every up-voter did silently fix the mistake without editing above.

Answer (score 11):

#more simple way to cover .env you can do like this

```
$_ENV['key'] = 'value';
```

Comment: Thanks @bty_cj for answering, I'm sure quite a few people will find this useful.

Comment: This is the only correct answer, and the only one that actually works. 

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 8):

### tl;dr

Based on [vesperknight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46396076/1494454) I created a solution that doesn't use [`strtok`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) or [`env()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-env).

```
private function setEnvironmentValue($envKey, $envValue)
{
    $envFile = app()->environmentFilePath();
    $str = file_get_contents($envFile);

    $str .= "\n"; // In case the searched variable is in the last line without \n
    $keyPosition = strpos($str, "{$envKey}=");
    $endOfLinePosition = strpos($str, PHP_EOL, $keyPosition);
    $oldLine = substr($str, $keyPosition, $endOfLinePosition - $keyPosition);
    $str = str_replace($oldLine, "{$envKey}={$envValue}", $str);
    $str = substr($str, 0, -1);

    $fp = fopen($envFile, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $str);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

### Explanation

This doesn't use `strtok` that might not work for some people, or `env()` that won't work with double-quoted `.env` variables which are evaluated and also interpolates embedded variables

```
KEY="Something with spaces or variables ${KEY2}"
```

Comment: This will modify #CACHE_DRIVER=... (if it is commented) instead of uncommented one (the real one)

Comment: Too bad! `PHP_EOL` changes based-on operating-system, but `.env` file's content not (at least usually), which is not handled above.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to save your changes to .env file, you could simply user this code :

```
\Illuminate\Support\Env::getRepository()->set('APP_NAME','New app name');
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me; used your code above in a controller method that returned a view, called `echo env("APP_NAME")` in the view, cleared caches, no change.

Comment: It works for me in a controller method then echo in a view with Laravel version 8.42.0

Comment: @miken32 i set this config in AppServiceProvider boot methods, to launch it first in the code.

Answer (score 4):

In the event that you want these settings to be persisted to the environment file so they be loaded again later (even if the configuration is cached), you can use a function like this.  I'll put the security caveat in there, that calls to a method like this should be gaurded tightly and user input should be sanitized properly.

```
private function setEnvironmentValue($environmentName, $configKey, $newValue) {
    file_put_contents(App::environmentFilePath(), str_replace(
        $environmentName . '=' . Config::get($configKey),
        $environmentName . '=' . $newValue,
        file_get_contents(App::environmentFilePath())
    ));

    Config::set($configKey, $newValue);

    // Reload the cached config       
    if (file_exists(App::getCachedConfigPath())) {
        Artisan::call("config:cache");
    }
}
```

An example of it's use would be;

```
$this->setEnvironmentValue('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'app.log_level', 'debug');
```

`$environmentName` is the key in the environment file (example.. APP_LOG_LEVEL)

`$configKey` is the key used to access the configuration at runtime (example.. app.log_level (tinker `config('app.log_level')`).

`$newValue` is of course the new value you wish to persist.

Comment: Could you please tell me to what file should i add this code ?

Comment: it says Config not found

Comment: Make sure you have ```use Config;``` at the top of the file

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change it temporarily (e.g. for a test), this should work for Laravel 8:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Dotenv\Repository\Adapter\ImmutableWriter;
use Dotenv\Repository\AdapterRepository;
use Illuminate\Support\Env;

class DynamicEnvironment
{
    public static function set(string $key, string $value)
    {
        $closure_adapter = \Closure::bind(function &(AdapterRepository $class) {
            $closure_writer = \Closure::bind(function &(ImmutableWriter $class) {
                return $class->writer;
            }, null, ImmutableWriter::class);
            return $closure_writer($class->writer);
        }, null, AdapterRepository::class);
        return $closure_adapter(Env::getRepository())->write($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
App\Helpers\DynamicEnvironment::set("key_name", "value");
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on totymedli's answer and Oluwafisayo's answer.

I set a little modification to change the .env file, It works too fine in Laravel 5.8, but when after I changed it the .env file was modificated I could see variables did not change after I restart with php artisan serve, so I tried to clear cache and others but I can not see a solution.

```
public function setEnvironmentValue(array $values)
{
    $envFile = app()->environmentFilePath();
    $str = file_get_contents($envFile);
    $str .= "\r\n";
    if (count($values) > 0) {
        foreach ($values as $envKey => $envValue) {

            $keyPosition = strpos($str, "$envKey=");
            $endOfLinePosition = strpos($str, "\n", $keyPosition);
            $oldLine = substr($str, $keyPosition, $endOfLinePosition - $keyPosition);

            if (is_bool($keyPosition) && $keyPosition === false) {
                // variable doesnot exist
                $str .= "$envKey=$envValue";
                $str .= "\r\n";
            } else {
                // variable exist                    
                $str = str_replace($oldLine, "$envKey=$envValue", $str);
            }            
        }
    }

    $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
    if (!file_put_contents($envFile, $str)) {
        return false;
    }

    app()->loadEnvironmentFrom($envFile);    

    return true;
}
```

So it rewrites correctly the .env file with the funtion setEnvironmentValue, but How can Laravel reload the new .env without to restart the system?

I was looking information about that and I found

```
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```

but in local it does not work! for me, but when I uploaded the code and test in my serve it works to fine.

I tested it in Larave 5.8 and worked in my serve...

This could be a tip when you have a variable with more than one word and separetly with a space, the solution i did

```
    public function update($variable, $value)
    {

        if ($variable == "APP_NAME" ||  $variable ==  "MAIL_FROM_NAME") {
            $value = "\"$value\"";
        }

        $values = array(
            $variable=>$value
            );
        $this->setEnvironmentValue($values);

        Artisan::call('config:clear');
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Tailor Otwell generate the laravel application key and set its value using this code (code modified for example purpose):

```
$escaped = preg_quote('='.config('broadcasting.default'), '/');

file_put_contents(app()->environmentFilePath(), preg_replace("/^BROADCAST_DRIVER{$escaped}/m", 'BROADCAST_DRIVER='.'pusher',
        file_get_contents(app()->environmentFilePath())
));
```

You can find the code in the key generation class:
`Illuminate\Foundation\Console\KeyGenerateCommand`

Answer (score 1):

PHP 8 solution

This solution is using `env()` so should only be run when the configuration is NOT cached.

```
/**
 * @param string $key
 * @param string $value
 */
protected function setEnvValue(string $key, string $value)
{
    $path = app()->environmentFilePath();
    $env = file_get_contents($path);

    $old_value = env($key);

    if (!str_contains($env, $key.'=')) {
        $env .= sprintf("%s=%s\n", $key, $value);
    } else if ($old_value) {
        $env = str_replace(sprintf('%s=%s', $key, $old_value), sprintf('%s=%s', $key, $value), $env);
    } else {
        $env = str_replace(sprintf('%s=', $key), sprintf('%s=%s',$key, $value), $env);
    }

    file_put_contents($path, $env);
}
```

Comment: How does it improve on any of the other half dozen answers writing to the `.env` file?

Answer (score 1):

for Laravel 10 and above, can use this package https://github.com/syamsoul/laravel-set-env ..

You can install it by run this command:

```
composer require syamsoul/laravel-set-env
```

.

and just simply do this in your code:

```
use SoulDoit\SetEnv\Env;

$envService = new Env(); 
$envService->set("MY_APP_NAME", "My Laravel Application");

// or set variable in .env.example file
$envService = new Env('.env.example');
$envService->set("MY_APP_NAME", "Localhost");
```

.

or you also can use Artisan command to set the env variable

```
php artisan souldoit:set-env "MY_APP_NAME=My Laravel Application"
```

or use -E switch to set the env file

```
php artisan souldoit:set-env "MY_APP_NAME=Localhost" -E .env.example

#or

php artisan souldoit:set-env "MY_APP_NAME=Localhost" --env_file_path=.env.example
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package
https://github.com/ImLiam/laravel-env-set-command

then use Artisan Facade to call artisan commands ex:

```
Artisan::call('php artisan env:set app_name Example')
```

Comment: I really didn't love this solution because it updates the .env file.  But if that's what you're looking for, then it's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

this function update new value of existing key or add new key=value to end of file

```
function setEnv($envKey, $envValue) {
  $path = app()->environmentFilePath();
  $escaped = preg_quote('='.env($envKey), '/');
  //update value of existing key
  file_put_contents($path, preg_replace(
    "/^{$envKey}{$escaped}/m",
    "{$envKey}={$envValue}",
    file_get_contents($path)
  ));
  //if key not exist append key=value to end of file
  $fp = fopen($path, "r");
  $content = fread($fp, filesize($path));
  fclose($fp);
  if (strpos($content, $envKey .'=' . $envValue) == false && strpos($content, $envKey .'=' . '\"'.$envValue.'\"') == false){
    file_put_contents($path, $content. "\n". $envKey .'=' . $envValue);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$envFile = app()->environmentFilePath();
$_ENV['APP_NAME'] = "New Project Name";
$txt= "";
foreach ($_ENV as $key => $value) {
    $txt .= $key."=".$value."\n"."\n";
}
file_put_contents($envFile,$txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

##### This solution can create, replace and save the values given in the .env file.

I created this to be used in a command `package:install` to add the .env key-value pairs automatically to the .env file.

```php
/**
 * Set .env key-value pair
 *
 * @param array $keyPairs Desired key name
 * @return void
 */
public function saveArrayToEnv(array $keyPairs)
{
    $envFile = app()->environmentFilePath();
    $newEnv = file_get_contents($envFile);

    $newlyInserted = false;

    foreach ($keyPairs as $key => $value) {
        // Make sure key is uppercase (can be left out)
        $key = Str::upper($key);

        if (str_contains($newEnv, "$key=")) {
            // If key exists, replace value
            $newEnv = preg_replace("/$key=(.*)\n/", "$key=$value\n", $newEnv);
        } else {
            // Check if spacing is correct
            if (!str_ends_with($newEnv, "\n\n") && !$newlyInserted) {
                $newEnv .= str_ends_with($newEnv, "\n") ? "\n" : "\n\n";
                $newlyInserted = true;
            }
            // Append new
            $newEnv .= "$key=$value\n";
        }
    }

    $fp = fopen($envFile, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $newEnv);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

You pass it an associative array:

```php
$keyPairs = [
    'KEY' => 'VALUE',
    'API_KEY' => 'XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX'
]
```

And it will add them or replace they values of the given keys with the given values.
Of course there is room for improvement like checking if the array is actually an associative array. But this will do for hard coded stuff in things like Laravel command classes.

Answer (score -1):

This solution builds upon the one provided by Elias Tutungi, it accepts multiple value changes and uses a Laravel Collection because foreach's are gross

```php
    function set_environment_value($values = [])
    {
        $path = app()->environmentFilePath();

        collect($values)->map(function ($value, $key) use ($path) {
            $escaped = preg_quote('='.env($key), '/');

            file_put_contents($path, preg_replace(
                "/^{$key}{$escaped}/m",
               "{$key}={$value}",
               file_get_contents($path)
            ));
        });

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this custom method i located from internet  ,

```
  /**
 * Calls the method 
 */
public function something(){
    // some code
    $env_update = $this->changeEnv([
        'DB_DATABASE'   => 'new_db_name',
        'DB_USERNAME'   => 'new_db_user',
        'DB_HOST'       => 'new_db_host'
    ]);
    if($env_update){
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
    // more code
}

protected function changeEnv($data = array()){
        if(count($data) > 0){

            // Read .env-file
            $env = file_get_contents(base_path() . '/.env');

            // Split string on every " " and write into array
            $env = preg_split('/\s+/', $env);;

            // Loop through given data
            foreach((array)$data as $key => $value){

                // Loop through .env-data
                foreach($env as $env_key => $env_value){

                    // Turn the value into an array and stop after the first split
                    // So it's not possible to split e.g. the App-Key by accident
                    $entry = explode("=", $env_value, 2);

                    // Check, if new key fits the actual .env-key
                    if($entry[0] == $key){
                        // If yes, overwrite it with the new one
                        $env[$env_key] = $key . "=" . $value;
                    } else {
                        // If not, keep the old one
                        $env[$env_key] = $env_value;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Turn the array back to an String
            $env = implode("\n", $env);

            // And overwrite the .env with the new data
            file_put_contents(base_path() . '/.env', $env);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

use the function below to change values in .env file laravel

```
 public static function envUpdate($key, $value)
{
    $path = base_path('.env');

    if (file_exists($path)) {

        file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
            $key . '=' . env($key), $key . '=' . $value, file_get_contents($path)
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Replace single value in .env file function**:

```
/**
 * @param string $key
 * @param string $value
 * @param null $env_path
 */
function set_env(string $key, string $value, $env_path = null)
{
    $value = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $value); //replace special ch
    $key = strtoupper($key); //force upper for security
    $env = file_get_contents(isset($env_path) ? $env_path : base_path('.env')); //fet .env file
    $env = str_replace("$key=" . env($key), "$key=" . $value, $env); //replace value
    /** Save file eith new content */
    $env = file_put_contents(isset($env_path) ? $env_path : base_path('.env'), $env);
}
```

Example to local (laravel) use: `set_env('APP_VERSION', 1.8)`.

Example to use custom path: `set_env('APP_VERSION', 1.8, $envfilepath)`.