# Is there a way to save values besides in the DataBase with Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying something crazy. The thing is that I need to save the Board of Directors number (the actual Board of Directors is the XXXVI but this year it will change to XXXVII) value on the variable because I think it is useless to make a table just to save a value that will change every 2 years. So it occurred to me using a global variable on the controller to save that value and everything goes wel with my code EXCEPT it's not saving the value into the variable. Here's my code:

Controller Code:

```
//Here I declare the variable
protected $board;

// Here I initialize the variable so I can send it to the template
public function editDirectors() 
{
    $numberBoard = $this->board;
    return view('board.edit_directors', compact('numberBoard'));
}

//Here it's supposed to save the value into the variable
public function uploadNumber(Request $request)
{
    $this->board = $request->value;
    $numberBoard = $this->board;
    return $numberBoard;
}
```

Template code:

```
<a href="#" id="board-number" data-type="text" 
                              data-pk="1" 
                              data-url="{{url('/board-of-directors/edit/number-board')}}"
                             data-value="{{$numberBoard}}" 
                             data-name="numberBoard" 
                             data-title="Number Board">{{$nummberBoard}}</a>
Board of Directors</h3>
```

X-Editable Initilization

```
$('#board-number').editable();
```

The Route

```
Route::put('/board-of-directors/edit/number-board' , 'DirectorController@uploadNumber');
```

The funny thing is that when I display the Web Console to check the Network Tab and inspect the XHR section it send a 200 Response and, in preview, it returns the value I enter but it doesn't save the value into the variable.

The help will be really appreciated :3

**EDIT:**

I created a config/board.php file and added this lines:

```
return [
'director' => [
    'number' => 'XXXVI'
]
];
```

Modified the Controller with this:

```
// Here I get the value at config/board.php and send it to the template and works :D
public function editDirectors() 
{
    $numberBoard = Config::get('board.director.number');
    return view('board.edit_directors', compact('numberBoard'));
}

//Here it's supposed to save the new value into the config/board.php file but doesn't works :(
public function uploadNumber(Request $request)
{
    $numberBoard = $request->value;
    Config::set('board.director.number', $numberBoard);
    return $numberBoard;
}
```

The I ran this command so the config/board.php could send the value to the controller.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Also, everytime I change the value at config/board.php it seems that I have to run this command to make it show the value.

Any ideas you could suggest? It will be really appreciated :3

Comment: so from what I understand is you want persistence storage but do not want to go to the database, so you can either save it in file or use Redis

Comment: @DhavalChheda So, there's no way I can save the value in the variable 'permanently'?

Comment: No variables are not persistent storage

Comment: @DhavalChheda That explains all. Thanks, I knew this would be a ultra noob question. I'll check Redis, sounds cool.

Comment: @RalphVB How frequently you are going to change the value? Once in a year? or what?

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham Every 2 years and it will only increase 1 number so that's why I see useless making a table in the DB to save it.

Comment: I would recommend to store it into `custom config file`. You can change it manually when you want, even you can change config file dynamically too but it's not a good idea to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can save this in config  or .env file.

Define in `.env`

```
DirectorNumber=XXVII
```

access in application Controller

```
protected $board;
function __construct($board)
{
    $this->$board = env('DirectorNumber');
}
```

Otherwise you can save this in config files

1. Create a board.php in config folder
2. In `config/board.php` write  `<?php return ['count' => 'XXVII'];`
3. access variable by `config('board.count')`

**edit**: in case of `config:cache` laravel doesn't pick updated env variable so either re-run `config:cache` or `config:clear` (it will start resuming env values in application)

Comment: I'll check both ways because the idea is that the user can change the number so I have to do it dynamically. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, I tried the env method but didn't worked BUT the custom config file worked EXCEPT that it doesn't save the value. Also I had to run the "php artisan config:cache" command to make it show the value of the config/board.php file.

I'll update the question :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I think what I did is a bad practice but it solved my problem.

Taken from: [How to set .env values in laravel programmatically on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450162/how-to-set-env-values-in-laravel-programmatically-on-the-fly?answertab=active#tab-top)

First I added this in my .env file:

```
BOARD_NUMBER = XXXVI
```

Then I updated my code in the Controller:

```
//Here I get the value form the BOARD_NUMBER at .env and send it to the template
public function editDirectors() 
{
    $numberBoard = env('BOARD_NUMBER');
    return view('board.edit_directors', compact('directors', 'numberBoard'));
}

//Here I open the .env and rewrite the BOARD_NUMBER value
protected function uploadNumber(Request $request)
{
    $numberBoard = $request->value;
    $envFile = app()->environmentFilePath();
    $str = file_get_contents($envFile);

    $oldValue = env('BOARD_NUMBER');

    $str = str_replace("BOARD_NUMBER={$oldValue}", "BOARD_NUMBER={$numberBoard}\n", $str);

    $fp = fopen($envFile, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $str);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

In the same link where I took the solution, there's another solution where the command "php artisan config:cache" runs but I doubt it works for me because I'm uploading the web app to a shared host.

Hopes this helps other :)