# How to set the laravel environment variable from controller using vlucas/phpdotenv

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Trying to set the environment variable from controller using phpdotenv package but it throws an  error **"Call to undefined method Dotenv\Dotenv::setEnvironmentVariable()"**

```
use Dotenv\Dotenv;
```

---

```
   $env = new Dotenv(app()->environmentPath(), app()->environmentFile());
   $env->setEnvironmentVariable('APP_ENV_TEST', 'testing');
```

Laravel Version: 5.6

vlucas/phpdotenv: 2.4

Comment: Quick question; why do you want the app to set `.env` variables? Also, Laravel offers a way to change them on the fly, using `config()->set("key", $value);`.

Comment: @TimLewis I want to set the key & value permanently in the env file.  ie. FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET

Comment: So set it manually via your terminal/editor of choice; I'm asking why you want the **app** to do it via a Controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set .env values in laravel programmatically on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450162/how-to-set-env-values-in-laravel-programmatically-on-the-fly)

Comment: @TimLewis I'm creating an admin panel using laravel. So that, i have to provide an option for admin users to change the environment variable from the UI without modifying the single line of code.

Comment: so this has nothing to do with the concept of 'env' in reality .. you just want to write to a file that happens to be the '.env' file?

Comment: is there any other way to load the config settings from the database or else provide way to write kay & value on env file