# How to send email from another address

Tags: laravel, mailgun, laravel-5.6

So I was wondering, how would I send my email from another email address in Laravel. Currently I have this email address and domain. This is an example. `Sender = test@domain.com`

Now I have many `auth()`

users. I want to be able for them to send emails as well. So how would I do that? So for an example: `Test@anotherdomain.com`

My point is, currently the admin guard is able to send an email to the owner of the post who is user(). I have multi auth so admin is one guard and the other is the default.

So the admin is able to send email to `test@domain.com`
 So how can I do it so that `test@anotherdomain.com` can send an email back to `test@domain.com`

Is this even possible?

Note: I am using mailgun.

Comment: Yes, just change env variables in runtime.

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad perhaps an example would work. What I am saying is to be able to use 2 domains. One is anotherdomain.com. And the other is domain.com. Auth user will send emails from anotherdomain.com and auth admin would send emails from domain.com

Answer (score 0):

You have two option in this situation:

1) use email clients independently like [Phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [Swiftmailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer)

2) [change the config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450162/how-to-set-env-values-in-laravel-programmatically-on-the-fly) file and email credentials on the fly(make sure your config isn't cached)

[Accessing Configuration Values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)