# Laravel 5.8 rest client how to save api token in the .env

Tags: api, laravel-5, token

I should like to `insert` the return token from api into the `.env` in when after i want pass it `header` in

```
<!-- language: php -->
    class GuzzleController extends Controller
    {
    public function getToken()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $request = $client->request('POST', 'http://192.168.53.27:1996/api/login/',
            [
                    'form_params' => [
                    'user_name' => 'userName',
                    'password' => 'Passs',
                ]
            ]);
        return json_decode((string)$request->getBody(), true);

    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use simple cache for that?

Comment: yes you right  i m looking now cache,  i m understand best way keep to token cache in because  of token temporary values have your handle cache how to used doc or sample tutorial

Comment: yes you right, simple cache best solutions

Answer (score 1):

As same question has been answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52548022/2185524);
This method should save new value to your .env file

```
private function setEnvironmentValue($envKey, $envValue)
{
    $envFile = app()->environmentFilePath();
    $str = file_get_contents($envFile);

    $str .= "\n"; // In case the searched variable is in the last line without \n
    $keyPosition = strpos($str, "{$envKey}=");
    $endOfLinePosition = strpos($str, PHP_EOL, $keyPosition);
    $oldLine = substr($str, $keyPosition, $endOfLinePosition - $keyPosition);
    $str = str_replace($oldLine, "{$envKey}={$envValue}", $str);
    $str = substr($str, 0, -1);

    $fp = fopen($envFile, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $str);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

usage

```
$this->setEnvironmentValue('DEPLOY_SERVER', 'forge@122.11.244.10');
```