# problem with updating laravel config 2020

Tags: php, laravel, config

I am working on local server the xampp

```
$pname=(string) $data->name;
config(['app.name' => $pname,'database.default' => 'mysql']);
```

Also run php artisan `config:clear` & `cache:clear` and all those command
also I stop Apache and start it again and the config still not updated

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `config still not updated`? What part of your code make you say that?

Comment: w h y are y o u typing l i k e that?

Comment: i tried to display config after update it like this
{{config("app.name");}} and it's still show the old name

Comment: @chojnicki am typing like that because stack over flow not allow for wrong syntax in his topic

Answer (score 0):

please do not try to access value directly from `config/app.php`. Since the **name** param, by default, uses `env(APP_NAME)`, I suggest doing `{{ env('APP_NAME', 'default') }}`.

Also, the reason why it's showing old value because in the **.env** file is not yet updated.

.env file
`APP_NAME=YourWebsite`

config/app
`'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'YourWebsite')`

in your blade file
`{{ env('APP_NAME', 'default') }}

Comment: اhello sir i see that but there is no way to edit env file from blade ?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? I can't seem to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: am actually try to make an install page for my script so in this install page i should be able to edit config to be like what the user want for example
data base name 
and database host
and database user 
..etc

Comment: I am sorry to say this but you **cannot** change `laravel php configs` with `scripts` running on client side.

Comment: am trying to edit the env from controller i think php is a server side lung ?

Comment: I found a link to another stack overflow question **How to set .env values in laravel programmatically on the fly** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450162/how-to-set-env-values-in-laravel-programmatically-on-the-fly

Comment: it seems to be my mistake :D i was returning value before setting the config sorry for bothering you sir

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be my mistake :D i was returning value before setting the config sorry for bothering you sir