# Laravel change .env file in controller

Tags: laravel, environment-variables

I have a multi tenancy app in laravel.
I change my .env file in Bootstrap->app depending on the domain name.

But now, I need change my .env file in a controller.
How I can change my .env file in a controller method?

I need to send a command for each domain and for each .env file without enter by domain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1**:

Since Laravel uses config files to access and store .env data.

```
config(['database.connections.mysql.host' => '127.0.0.1']);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40450184/4721265)

**solution 2**:

The following code might help:

```
public function something(){
// some code
$env_update = $this->changeEnv([
    'DB_DATABASE'   => 'new_db_name',
    'DB_USERNAME'   => 'new_db_user',
    'DB_HOST'       => 'new_db_host'
]);
if($env_update){
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
// more code
```

}

[Reference](https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/change-the-env-dynamically)