# How to set a variable environment Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

After following [Alexey's topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450162/how-to-set-env-values-in-laravel-programmatically-on-the-fly), I can't find any solution to modify environment variables in Laravel 7. I would like to modify a variable in a controller and then call it in a view. Without success

My controller:

```
public function modifyBanner(Request $request)
    {
        config(['app.banner' => $request->banner]);
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', "Bannière modifiée");
    }
```

My view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="banner" @if (!env('BANNER')) placeholder="Message à insérer" @else placeholder="{{ env('BANNER') }}"  value="{{ env('BANNER') }}" @endif>
```

Comment: config() can't find my variable that I just set...

Comment: Because you are redirect and redirect is a new request lifecycle and your banner will not be there.

Comment: Do you want to update .env variable value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When redirecting, a new Request lifecycle is born, it is basicly loading a new page. Instead use `with()` and `session` to access your banner.

```
return redirect()->back()
    ->with('success', "Bannière modifiée")
    ->with('banner', $request->banner);
```

So in a controller context you can access it like so.

```
$request->session()->get('banner');
```

Or in a blade file.

```
{{ session()->get('banner')  }}
```