# Create or get Stripe customer in two different Stripe accounts

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-8, laravel-cashier

I have two Stripe accounts:

```
# Stripe API Keys
STRIPE_KEY=pk_test_abc
STRIPE_SECRET=sk_test_abc
STRIPE_KEY_MAPPING=pk_test_opr
STRIPE_SECRET_MAPPING_MASTER=sk_test_opr
```

I put both in an array:

```
$stripe_accounts = [
    env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
    env('STRIPE_SECRET_MAPPING_MASTER')
]
```

Now I want to create user in both accounts :

```
foreach ($stripe_accounts as $item) {
  Stripe::setApiKey($item);
  $hotel = session('hotel');
  $stripeUser = $hotel->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
  $hotel->updateDefaultPaymentMethodFromStripe();
}
```

I have no errors, but when I check stripe dashboard for this account `STRIPE_KEY_MAPPING` I don't see any test data. How can I make a flow in which I create same Stripe customer in two different accounts?

Comment: I'm not sure `Stripe::setApiKey()` will affect Cashier. Cashier uses its own instance. https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/ddb8311db517b6268d7b2497c95075afb6f40989/src/Cashier.php#L104

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, thx for the info. Btw you had an idea how I can do this flow ?

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel Cashier gets Stripe API keys from the `.env` file](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#api-keys), which [uses the DotEnv library](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#environment-configuration).

Try the approaches in the answers to this question to change the Stripe API keys in your code: [How to set .env values in laravel programmatically on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450162/how-to-set-env-values-in-laravel-programmatically-on-the-fly)