# Create stripe customer for 2 companies in the same time

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-8, laravel-cashier

I have 2 different stripe accounts :

```
# Stripe Keys Account 1
STRIPE_KEY=pk_test_abc
STRIPE_SECRET=sk_test_abc

# Stripe Keys Account 2
STRIPE_KEY_MAPPING=pk_test_opr
STRIPE_SECRET_MAPPING_MASTER=sk_test_opr
```

I put in an array :

```
$stripe_accounts = [
  env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
  env('STRIPE_SECRET_MAPPING_MASTER')
];
```

I want to create customer in both accounts in the same time :

```
foreach ($stripe_accounts as $item) {
  $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($item);
  $hotel = session('hotel');
  $stripeUser = $hotel->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
  $hotel->updateDefaultPaymentMethodFromStripe();
}
```

Is not working as expected, because create customer just for `Account 1` that have `STRIPE_KEY`.

Have you an idea about that ?

Comment: don't duplicate your [own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69183764/create-or-get-stripe-customer-in-2-differents-stripe-accounts)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create or get stripe customer in 2 differents stripe accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69183764/create-or-get-stripe-customer-in-2-differents-stripe-accounts)

Comment: @stui no :((((..